# Average Sample Number using Page's CUSUM procedure?

Tags: r, mathematical-statistics, sequential-analysis

I am trying reproduce the Table 1 results from the page 12 using the equation given the page 13.To access the journal article please click https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0605322.pdf.  The corresponding equation is given below.

$$T(\theta_{0},a) = \inf\{n\geq 1 : \max_{1\leq k\leq n}\sum_{i=k}^{n}\log\frac{g_{\lambda}(X_{i})}{f_{\theta_{0}}(X_{i})}\geq a\}$$

When $g_{\lambda}(X_{i})\sim N(0,1)$ and $f_{\theta_{0}}(X_{i}) \sim N(\theta_{0},1)$ where  $\theta_{0} = (-0.5,-1.0)$ 
$$T(\theta_{0},a) = \inf\{n\geq 1 : \max_{1\leq k\leq n}\sum_{i=k}^{n}(-\theta_{0})[X_{i} - \theta_{0}/2]\geq a\}$$

My `r code` is give below. Am I programmed correctly?

```
mytest=function(n,s,c1){
  t = sum(s)
  k=which.max(s[19:n]>=c1)
  if(k==1 && s[19]<c1) 
    return(c(n,0)) 
  else 
    return(c(k,1))
}


for (n in c(100,200,400)){

for (i in c(-0.5, -1.0)){
a1=0
c1 = 20
asn1=0
for (m in 1:1000){
  g=c(dnorm(n,0,1))
  f=c(dnorm(n,i,1))
  s = log(g/f)
  test=mytest(n,s,c1)
  a1=a1+test[2]
  asn1=asn1+test[1]
}

}
out <- list(power= a1/m, asn=asn1/m)
return(out)
}
```

But I am getting the following errors.

```
Error in if (k == 1 && s[19] < c1) return(c(n, 0)) else return(c(k, 1)) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Thank you very much for your suggestion.